# How to run the program while it is away from the database file?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm trying to run my program it is away from the SQLite database file BUT there is an exception raised that says

`Data Source cannot be empty.  Use :memory: to open an in-memory database`

Here is my code

```cs
static string path;
static SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={path};Pooling=true;FailIfMissing=false;Version=3");

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) path = ofd.FileName;
    OpenDB();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a shortcut from the folder of my project.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to create connection object when you have `path` value assigned.

```cs
SQLiteConnection cnn; // requires not to be accessed until assigned
// hosting connection in the form is not the best idea so you may try to create data access object (additional class) with DB access implemented in this new class 

void OpenDB(string filename)
{
 // you may want to add existing connection check and disposing code here 
 cnn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=" + filename + ";Pooling=true;FailIfMissing=false;Version=3");
}
```

it should be used like

```cs
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            path = ofd.FileName;
            OpenDB(path);
        }
```

Comment: there is another exception raised says 'No connection associated with this command'

Comment: @MahmoudMohamedRamadan please check [this guide how to create command](http://zetcode.com/csharp/sqlite/) for connection